# Certbot command in docker-compose issues SSL certificate with invalid CA

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, certbot

## The problem

I'm trying to use `certbot` to auto-generate a TLS certificate for Nginx in my multi-container Docker configuration. Everything works as expected except the Certificate Authority (CA) is invalid.

When I visit my site, I see that `Fake LE Intermediate X1`, an invalid authority, issued the certificate:

[image]

### My setup

Here is the **docker-compose.yml** file where I call `certbot` to generate the certificate:

```
version: '2'
services:
  apollo:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network
    build: .
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --noninteractive --keep-until-expiring --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email myemail@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d mydomain.com
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
    depends_on:
      - apollo
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  postgres: ~
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/user/project_name/dhparam/
      o: bind
  web-root:

networks:
  app-network:
```

I don't *think* that Nginx is the issue because the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect works, and the browser receives a certificate. But just in case it's relevant: here's the **nginx.conf** where I refer to the certificate and configure an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect.

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;        
    server_name mydomain.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @apollo;
    }

    location @apollo {
      proxy_pass http://apollo:1337;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
      add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
      add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    }

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  }
}
```

### What I've tried

1. Initially, I called `certonly` with the `--staging` argument in the `cerbot` container definition in `docker-compose.yml`. This could definitely cause the invalid CA problem. However, I have since tried revoking the CA and re-running the command multiple times, but no luck.
2. I have tried removing the `--keep-until-expiring` flag in the `cerbot` container definition of `docker-compose.yml`. This causes `cerbot` to generate a new certificate, but it did not resolve the CA issue.
3. Visiting [crt.sh](https://crt.sh/), I can see that certbot did issue valid certificates for my domain:

[image]

So, the problem seems to lie not in the generation of these certificates, but in the way my docker-compose/cerbot configuration is referring to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the `--force-renewal` flag:

```
command: >-
  certonly
  --webroot
  --webroot-path=/var/www/html
  --email myemail@example.com
  --agree-tos
  --no-eff-email
  --force-renewal
  -d mydomain.com
```